# Might Have You Ever? Might Had You Ever?

Tags: grammar, tense, word-order, auxiliary-verbs

> Might have you ever read that book?

I read that you may use something like this.

> Might had you ever read that book?

May you use something, like this?

I think I may have just thought something like *might* seems, maybe, passed for may. So, I thought to, maybe, use *had*. I guess, I thought, if they maybe read it, then they may not read it, now. Or, maybe, they read some, of it, and may not read it, now.

Answer (score 1):

Those sentences are wrong: they do not follow the grammatical rules of English, and natives would not say or write them. When a verb has multiple auxiliaries, in a question, the subject comes immediately after the first auxiliary and before the second auxiliary. The same thing goes for adverbs that are placed before the verb, such as *ever* here; it would also apply to a negation.

> Might you ever have read that book?
>   Might you not have read that book?

These sentences are grammatically correct, but they sound weird. “Might” is uncommon in yes-no questions since it refers to a possibility; an answer “yes, I might” doesn't actually say anything. “Might” *can* be used in a question, but it has a de-intensification effect, whereas “ever” has an intensitification effect.

> Might you have read that book? Perhaps you read it a long time ago in school and you've now forgotten it?

vs.

> Have you ever read that book? If you did, I'm sure you'll remember it.

As for “*Might you had …”, it's ungrammatical for another reason: “had” is a past tense (it could be either a simple past or a past participle), but “might” must be followed by an infinitive. To combine “might” with a past tense, you need to use a compound past (“might have read”), and you can't make a past perfect (if a past perfect is needed due to tense sequencing, a compound past will be used instead).

Comment: I guess, I maybe thought *might* seemed like passed. So, I guess, I may not get why you may not get to utilize a passed verb, to it, and you may use an infinitive. And, may you use something like *Might you ever have had read that book?*?

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: this sentence is wrong - see below] 'Might have you ...?' *is* (just) possible but is extremely rare (Google Ngram - [by itself](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=might%20have%20you&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmight%20have%20you%3B%2Cc0) and [with 'have you'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=might%20have%20you%2Chave%20you&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmight%20have%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chave%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhave%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHave%20you%3B%2Cc0)) and extremely awkward. [This sentence is still true] More natural questions are 'Might you possibly have read ...?' or 'Is is possible that you have read ...?'.

'Might you had ...' is grammatically incorrect. 'Might' (and all other modal verbs) *must* be followed by a verb in its base form - 'have', *not* 'has' or 'had' or 'having'.

Where did you read or hear these sentences, or did you write them yourself?

[Edit: I have thought about my answer overnight, and my first paragraph is wrong. The standard statement form is 'You might have read ...', so the standard question form is 'Might you have read ...?', *not*  'Might have you read ...' (though some people might say that, accidentally or otherwise) in informal speech. The other issue is the placement of 'ever'. 'Might you ever have read ...' is probably more standard than 'Might you have ever read ...' but neither of them shows up on Google Ngrams.]

Comment: I think, I, may, see. I think, I thought this modal(?), *might*, seemed passed, for *may*. So, I guess, I maybe thought to maybe use a passed for *have*. And, I think, I thought, what if they, maybe, have not read through the book? May *have* mean they, maybe, did, and, or, may *have* mean that they still may, maybe, read it?

Comment: 'Might' is very often the past equivalent of 'may' (but it has other uses as well), but that doesn't mean the word which comes after it is past as well. In 'May do', 'Might do', 'May have done', 'Might have done' etc, the verb after 'may/might' is always in its base form, and the verb after 'have' is always in its past participle form.

Comment: I can't follow what you're claiming in this answer. Please rewrite it without the bits you now think are wrong and without edit marks. The rare people who are interested in your post's history can click on the history link.